# Why is *.localhost resolved automatically on Ubuntu but not on MacOS?

Tags: subdomain, localhost, hosts, hosts-file

I have the same hosts file on both Ubuntu and MacOS.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

On Ubuntu:

```
my-ubuntu$ ping foo.localhost
PING foo.localhost(ip6-localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.129 ms
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.073 ms
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
...
```

On MacOs:

```
my-mac$ ping foo.localhost
ping: cannot resolve foo.localhost: Unknown host
```

Why are subdomains of localhost automatically resolving on Ubuntu but not on MacOS?

Comment: [How does linux resolve wildcard locahost subdomains (e.g. : `ping test.localhost`) when `test.localhost` does not exist in /etc/hosts or dns server?](https://superuser.com/questions/1653348/how-does-linux-resolve-wildcard-locahost-subdomains-e-g-ping-test-localhost)

Comment: @Bert: Using the standard resolver library call it will be done based on nsswitch.conf, hosts and resolv.conf. Like Unix systems usually do. And if it goes finally to a DNS server then it is dependant on its config. And, well, there's one beasty service on Linux which macOS doesn't have: systemd/systemd-resolver.

Comment: Your question is missing some important things like resolv.conf (and maybe nsswitch.conf).

Answer (score 0):

Reason is most probably the systemd-resolvd.

Checking configs:

```
root@sf:~# grep localhost /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
root@sf:~# grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

127.0.0.53 is the systemd resolver.

Now do pings:

```
root@sf:~# ping -c 1 foo.localhost
PING foo.localhost(ip6-localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
--- foo.localhost ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.035/0.035/0.035/0.000 ms

root@sf:~# ping -c 1 serverfault.com
PING serverfault.com (151.101.129.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.129.69 (151.101.129.69): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=16.8 ms
--- serverfault.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 16.802/16.802/16.802/0.000 ms
```

Yes, it works exactly like your ping.

Now switch from systemd resolver to my LAN's dns cache:

```
root@sf:~# sed -i '/nameserver/s,.*,nameserver 192.168.101.1,' /etc/resolv.conf
root@sf:~# grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.101.1
```

Doing pings again:

```
root@sf:~# ping -c 1 foo.localhost
ping: foo.localhost: Name or service not known
root@sf:~# ping -c 1 serverfault.com
PING serverfault.com (151.101.129.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.129.69 (151.101.129.69): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=16.4 ms
--- serverfault.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 16.426/16.426/16.426/0.000 ms
```

Voila!